# In which systems is segmentation with paging (segmented paging) memory management technique used? Give some examples

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, history, memory-segmentation

I’m a student studying OS and I cannot find a document or something that talks about the history of memory management like where segmented paging was applied and why they don't use this anymore (because I saw somebody say that modern OSes prefer to use paging instead of segmentation). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469253/does-linux-not-use-segmentation-but-only-paging) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which systems is segmentation with paging (segmented paging) memory management technique used?

The only systems that were capable of using both segmentation and paging at the same time for memory management that I'm aware of are:

a) OS/2 ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2 ) where it was optional and each process could choose "segmented with paging" or "flat paging" and most processes chose "flat paging".

b) Old versions of 32-bit Windows when running even older programs designed for 16-bit Windows (which were designed for "segmentation without any paging")

c) A few (maybe just one) hobbyist and/or niche operating systems that lack notoriety

Note 1: This excludes systems that use segmentation for something else and don't use segmentation for memory management (specifically, recycling an "otherwise unused segment register" so it can be used like a pointer to thread local storage to avoid wasting a more useful general purpose register).

Note 2: I can't guarantee that there isn't one or more other systems that I'm not aware of.